# If a referenced Java class is not found, or blacklisted, when is this detected?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, classloader

I wanted to use, inside Google appengine, a small library; one of the methods of one of its classes (say `MyClass.writeToFile()`) uses `java.io.FileOutputStream`, which is among the  blacklisted classes (well, not [white-listed](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html)).

Does this imply that `MyClass` will fail at classloading time, or just when (if) I try to invoke the offending method? At what point is that checking ("FileOutputStream not allowed") done? When loading `MyClass` file and detecting that it "refers to/depends on" FileOutputStream  (I dont know if this is declared in the `MyClass`  bytecode)? Or when trying to load `FileOutputStream`, while invoking `MyClass.writeToFile()`  for the first time?

Further, assuming that the method `MyClass.writeToFile()` is not essential for my library (but `MyClass` is), is there some workaround, or should one refactor the library (and build, say two different jars, one full fledged and other sandbox-friendly) ?

Comment: Why is `java.io.FileInputStream` allowed but not `java.io.FileOutputStream`?

Comment: @JAB: Because Google AE tolerates to be read but not to be written. Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a test deploy. Deployment should fail if I remember it correctly. Classes that are used by a certain class is part of the byte code, and google is verifying it.

Edit: I'm contradicting myself :)  This thread indicates that deployment only fail if the FileOutputStream class is loaded: 
[GoogleAppEngine : possible to disable FileUpload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569651/googleappengine-possible-to-disable-fileupload)

Edit2: And this indicates that it is the class loader that is checking / stopping loading of forbidden classes: [The Sandbox](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Sandbox)

Comment: Which again begs the question: FileOutputStream class is loaded when MyClass is loaded on when MyClass.writeToFile() is invoked? Or does this depend on the particular classloader?

Comment: The class might be loaded when your class is loaded, but it's up to the classloader.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are lazyload upon first reference. If your code never tries to use FileOutputStream then there should be no problem.